# Android NativeActivity. How to do some job in other thred?

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading

I have my own activity class extends from NativeActivity. I need to do a large work on c++ side(work with large text file). So i want to do this in separete thread. Also i want to do this on c++ side using pthread. Is it possible or i can use threads only on java side? I will be very thankful if will get links about using threads in applications based on NativeActivity.thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can use posix threads in native C++. Still, it is not good to implement long running jobs in activities at all because their life cycles are specifically managed. Use background services for that. In such service you can use JNI for C/C++ embedding and in that part you can work with posix threads. For example, we use boost threads with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to my code looks like below....................

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//Reference Variable
    Context con;

    TextView tv_start;


    Thread t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tv_start            = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_start);



\
//Start Button Functionality
         tv_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {

                 t = new Thread() {
                     @Override
                     synchronized public void run() {
                         try {
                             while (!isInterrupted() && pause) {
                                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void run() {

                                    // do you  need

                                     }  // run close

                                 }); // Runnable close

                             }
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         }
                     }
                 };
                 t.start();
             }
         });


    } // onCreate method close
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Creating Threads in the Native level is possible.

Assuming that you know how to call a native C/C++ function, I am giving you this simple code for reference.

Creating Threads using pthread is same as in the linux.

```
pthread_t threadID; // declaration

void Start()
{
    // Thread which is running in your native level
    while(1)
    {
        //your code goes here
    }
}

void StartThread()
{
    // This function should be called from java level 
    int res = 0;
    res = pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, Start, NULL);
    if(res!=null)
        print thread created
    else
        not created
}
```